# Why sortBy sorts differently than stream sorting in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sorting, kotlin

I have the list of beans autowired by an interface in my application with Kotlin and Spring-boot.

```
@Autowired
private var pages: List<Paging>
```

In post construct i sort beans by class simple name

```
@PostConstruct
fun setUp(){
 pages.sortedBy { it.javaClass.simpleName }
 pages.forEach { log.info("{}", it::class.simpleName) }
}
```

I see next results

```
page.month.Page19M@69cf9dd
page.month.Page04@43be5d62
page.month.Page03@5d34e3b3
page.month.Page13@151b7c03
page.month.Page16@6e71c9dc
page.month.Page17@7fe14f94
page.month.Page12@1f502e65
page.month.Page18@7d4d32a7
page.month.Page07@65c29c4c
page.month.Page06@5387e079
page.month.Page15@249dd7e6
page.month.Page11@56f13088
page.month.Page14@29ef49a1
page.month.Page10@76dc4e
page.month.Page09@c59b505
page.month.Page01@30c6e2e
page.month.Page02w@46bde78e
page.month.Page05@7500f8f0
page.month.Page08@7c5810e4
```

Beans weren't sorted by simple name.

But when i use stream style

```
pages.stream()
     .sorted { o1, o2 -> o1.javaClass.simpleName.compareTo(o2.javaClass.simpleName) }
     .forEach { i -> log.info("{}", i.javaClass.simpleName) }
```

I see sorted results

```
page.month.Page01@30c6e2e
page.month.Page02w@46bde78e
page.month.Page03@5d34e3b3
page.month.Page04@43be5d62
page.month.Page05@7500f8f0
page.month.Page06@5387e079
page.month.Page07@65c29c4c
page.month.Page08@7c5810e4
page.month.Page09@c59b505
page.month.Page10@76dc4e
page.month.Page11@56f13088
page.month.Page12@1f502e65
page.month.Page13@151b7c03
page.month.Page14@29ef49a1
page.month.Page15@249dd7e6
page.month.Page16@6e71c9dc
page.month.Page17@7fe14f94
page.month.Page18@7d4d32a7
page.month.Page19M@69cf9dd
```

I don't understand why results are different.
I tried use just a class with a field - works ok.

What do i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sortedBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) method in the Kotlin Standard Library does not perform in-place sorting. Instead, it **returns a new sorted list**.

In the code you have shared, you sort the list using `pages.sortedBy{ ... }` but ignore the result of this operation. The `pages` variable therefore remains unmodified, and you get the same list as before when you iterate over it using `forEach`.

If you instead iterate over the sorted list, you'll get the desired result:

```
val sortedPages = pages.sortedBy { page -> page.javaClass.simpleName }
sortedPages.forEach { sortedPage -> println(sortedPage) }
```

You can shorten this further by iterating directly over the result returned after sorting the list:

```
pages.sortedBy { page -> page.javaClass.simpleName }
     .forEach { sortedPage -> println(sortedPage) }
```

You can try out this [sample code](https://pl.kotl.in/-pqd8xlnH) to verify.

Comment: Good answer.  It may also help to mention the `sortBy()` method, which _does_ sort in-place.  (In general, the Kotlin stdlib uses verbs like `sort` for in-place operations, and adjectives like `sorted` for operations which return a result without changing the object itself.)